# System beep not working in TigerVNC

Tags: xorg, audio, vnc

I just upgraded my Gentoo Linux computer (where I'm running Xvnc from [TigerVNC](http://www.tigervnc.org/) 1.0.90 (1.1 beta 1) compiled myself against xorg-server 1.9.5), and I'm no longer getting any bell sounds, just silence.  (In particular, when I hit Ctrl-G in Emacs.)  This used to work before the upgrades.  (I upgraded quite a lot of things, unfortunately, so I'm not really sure which one caused it.)

I double-checked my viewer settings, and "Beep when requested" is checked.  I do get beeps when they're generated by a program on my local computer, so it must be the server that isn't sending beep requests.

How can I fix this?